# Different behaviour of plots on Octave-CLI and Octave-GUI

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I use Octave v 4.4.1 and it has been observed that I get different looking plots while plotting using Octave-CLI and Octave-GUI. I had configured the graphics_toolkit to be Gnuplot.

Plot using Octave - CLI :

[image: Octave-CLI plot]

Plot using Octave - GUI :

[image: Octave-GUI plot]

I am unsure why such a difference exists between the plots.  Is there a way by which I can get the behaviour of Octave-GUI plot on Octave-CLI? It will be well appreciated if someone can say about the reason why the differences happen to be so.

Comment: Which system, octave and gnuplot do you have? For me graphics_toolkit `gnuplot` always produce the first image and `qt` produces something similar to the second image.

Comment: I use  Kubuntu v18.10 as operating system. Octave version - 4.4.1 and Gnuplot version - 5.2.  Both the images are Gnuplots and I don't understand why it behaves differently.